# need a little modification in the query

Tags: php, mysql

The query I'm using for getting post against the current user (`userID`).It is working 100%. It gives me all those posts related of second person and first person. What I want is  `userID`  should also be included in the result on executing the query.

query:

[image: query]

[image: on execution of query]

[image: post table]

[image: friends table]

In the above images first image show the query which i have written above it gives me result of two user.Second picture is showing the whole table of post.

In that table one post is done by the current user (1).I also want to include that in the result of the query.So what changes should i make in the code to make it happen.
I want to include the user information corresponding to the `userId` in to the post result

Comment: Actually what result you want ?

Comment: the `userID(1)` on the behalf i m executing the query is also need int he result.

Comment: You can say the result must contain result of `userID(1)`.Is it clear?

Comment: You mean you wan to include the user information coresponding to the userId in to the post result?

Comment: yes you are right that's what i want

Comment: OK i'm kinda undetstand what you want.

Comment: :D so i m waiting for your your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131448/discussion-between-teck-wei-and-awais-ahmad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE userID = 1 OR userID IN (SELECT FirstPersonID FROM friends WHERE SecondFriendID =1)
```

BTW what does <> mean?

Comment: Please let me know izzit work? I recently also develop social media app but i'm using follow system rather than friend system I could teach how some techique to enhance your sql code

Comment: hehehehe thanks a lot man that's it when i was trying it. It didn't work :P .You have done a magic :D

Comment: By the way don't include postUserFullName inside your post table put it inside another table use left join instead.

Comment: ok i have another little question to ask wait i m send the link

Comment: can you answer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319913/implement-a-share-button-like-facebook-share-button

Comment: can you answer that